# Какая разница между int* const и const int*?

Tags: c++, указатели, const

Какая разница между `int* const` и `const int*` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const int*`  — это неконстантный указатель, который указывает на неизменное(константное) значение.
`int* const` — это константный указатель, эго нельзя заставить указывать на другую область памяти.

Answer (score 5):

Первый - постоянный указатель на `int`. То, на что он указывает, менять можно, но не саму переменную с указателем.

Второй - указатель на постоянный `int`.  То, на что он указывает, менять нельзя, но сама переменная с указателем может получить новое значение и указывать на что-то другое.

Так понятно?

Попробуйте скомпилировать

```
int a[2];
const int * p = &a[0];
*p = 2;
p = &a[1];
```

и посмотрите, на что ругнется компилятор. Потом поставьте `const` в другое место и снова скомпилируйте..